# The life of static attributes

Tags: php, static

Let's say I have a `Route` class, and I call a couple of times `Route::set()` method. This method does one thing:

```
self::objects[] = new Route();
```

which is saving the `Route` instance inside the class attribute array.

What will happen in this situation? Logically, `set()` will create a lot of `Route` instances, and each of them will have objects array with one element.

But accorting to the code I'm researching right now, the objects array will contain all objects of the `Route` class.

Which one is correct, and most importantly - why?

EDIT. I know the title sucks, but I couldnt figured the better one out...it's 2 a.m., Im not thinking.

Comment: Perhaps if it is 2am (and that makes you living is Asia) it might be a good idea to sleep.

Answer (score 0):

The array will contain all objects of the class. A static property is basically a global variable under its guise of a different name, and is not specific to any instance of the class.

Comment: Wow, that's surprising. Just to make everything clear - many Route::set() still refer to different class instances?

Comment: @user2203484: Yes, that's right. The `set` is still individual for each instance, but the `objects` property is shared between all of them.